# ThreadPool vs Task Parallel Library

Tags: .net, threadpool, task-parallel-library

I've used both, the thread pool and TPL in different scenarios. Moving forward, it would be helpful to have a better understanding of what each is suited for. Here are two different scenarios to comment against. Which approach would be better?

- Download Manager: Each file segment is to be appended to the target file in a particular order.
- Document Processing: Multiple documents are processed in parallel but have no inter-dependencies so order is not important.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Sorry, the question is which of the options would be better suited to those two scenarios and why? TPL or ThreadPool?

Comment: There is a discussion of TPL vs. ThreadPool in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx